# Python- format of output file

Tags: python, colorama

in my program i have used context manager as a wrapper to output terminal text in a text file as result output. later decided to change terminal text color using python colorama module, now the *.txt file text has ANSI codes (from colorama) all over the file.

can i change the file extension from *.txt to any other suitable format so that the output file contents will have the same color formats as terminal? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, you can't. You'd have to use a more advanced format, like HTML, or something like that.

Note that the file can still be output in the terminal with the `cat` command, and it will show the colors just fine.

```
cat file.txt
```